# 'container' got despaired from the GROUPS list in the gcloud

Tags: gcloud

**What was done before the issues occurs:**

I had [the problem](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=157). I have solved it by re-installing the gcloud with the command:

> gcloud components reinstall

however as a result I am facing the new issue with the 'container' group

**The Issue**

> ```
> ~ gcloud beta container get-credentials
> ...
> ERROR: (gcloud.preview) Invalid choice: 'container'.
> ~ gcloud preview container
> ...
> ERROR: (gcloud.preview) Invalid choice: 'container'.
> ~ gcloud beta container get
> ...
> ERROR: (gcloud.beta) Invalid choice: 'container'.
> ~ gcloud preview container
> ...
> ERROR: (gcloud.preview) Invalid choice: 'container'.
> ~ gcloud components container
> ...
> ERROR: (gcloud.components) Invalid choice: 'container'.
> ```

**What I've tried already**

- gcloud components update preview
- gcloud components update beta
- gcloud components update preview app
- gcloud components update app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem have been solved by manual [re-install gcloud from scratch](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/)